# How do I show another user my flag history?

Tags: discussion, flagging

[aditya patil](https://askubuntu.com/users/184942/aditya-patil) asked for my flag history in my nomination discussion [here](https://askubuntu.com/election/4?noredirect=1#post-419884). How can I provide my flagging history?

---

EDIT: This is a screenshot of my flag history:

[image]

Comment: Your helpful flags count is shown as part of your nomination. This should be sufficient for most cases. (It's shown left of your user info)

Comment: This will work for me, at least.lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could print screen your flag history from your profile and that's enough. I don't know if there is another way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Your flag history is private. You only (any maybe mods, not sure) can view it but other users can't.

I can't see yours; you can't see mine.

Thus, the best way to share your flag stats is via a screenshot or just copying the text.

Comment: I did so but i'm asking if i can do it another way

Comment: @maythux: Any way which doesn't involve the end user reading it from the link will work. You need to transcribe it somehow and provide this to the end user (screenshot and copying does this).